# What kind of bird is outside my window?

Tags: birds, bird-watching, bird-identification

I live in Phoenix, Arizona, USA. Recently, there has been a bird sitting in the mesquite tree outside my window, singing. This bird comes in the middle of the damn night. Once 3am, once 5am, and now around midnight.

What is peculiar about this bird is that it makes so many different sounds.

I recorded a video of its calls coming from my window:
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=eHusuJlkXa8

What is this bird?

Comment: That’s really interesting!

Comment: Hi chester. In addition to @Ricketyship's identification, I want to confirm that Northern Mockingbirds are year round residents in Arizone. See [this page](http://www.birderfrommaricopa.com/mockingbirds-and-thrashers.htm) for information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The bird you are listening to is a [northern mocking bird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_mockingbird). I am not sure why it’s making the calls in the middle of the night.

Mockingbirds in general are known for their intelligence and their ability to learn new calls. That’s why you’ll mostly hear it making a lot of different types of calls.

**EDIT:**

After some research I found the following reasons why a mockingbird would sing at night:

- The one singing is an [unmatched or bachelor](http://www.birdwatching.com/stories/mockingbird.html) and is desperate to find a mate.
- The [lights of the city](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-mockingbirds-sing-at-night) and the hormones activate the mockingbird to think it's already morning.

I haven't come across any scientific study to back either of these claims.

Comment: @Sue link seems to be working for me. Can you access [this](http://www.birdwatching.com/stories/mockingbird.html) link?

Comment: For what it's worth, Mockingbirds are noted for singing quite late in the year as well as at night.  Our local ones in Maryland are still singing vigorously, for instance, at a time when the only other songs are Carolina Wrens (also very late singers).  It may be related to the fact that Mockingbirds are fiercely territorial and establish winter territories where fruit can be found.  Somebody may have already looked into this, but I haven't noticed any papers on it.